# Долгий запуск android приложения

Tags: java, android, boot

Очень долго запускается приложение (в этом примере 40 секунд) если запуск происходит впервые, потом запускается быстро.

Пробовал на простой активности (хотя есть и рабочие):

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "SplashActivity";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Проект состоит из двух рабочих модулей.

Модуль app:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.github.ParkSangGwon:TedPermission:v1.0.8'
compile 'com.vk:androidsdk:1.6.5'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.1'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.1'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.1'
compile project(':libw')
}
```

Модуль libw:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'

compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.19.0'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.19.0'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.19.0'
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.19.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'
compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.6.1'

compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.0'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.7@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile files('libs/m3u8parser-0.2.jar')

jaxDoclet("com.google.doclava:doclava:1.0.5")
classpaths fileTree(dir: 'build/classes/release').matching { include 'io/x/sdk/S.java' }
}
```

Лог:

```
07-04 17:18:37.893 31219-31219/com.sapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.sapp-1/lib/arm
07-04 17:19:17.429 31219-31219/com.sapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.sapp-1/lib/arm
07-04 17:19:17.488 31219-31219/com.sapp D/SplashActivity: onCreate
07-04 17:19:17.513 31219-31219/com.sapp D/SplashActivity: onStart
07-04 17:19:17.513 31219-31219/com.sapp D/SplashActivity: onResume
07-04 17:19:17.522 31219-31875/com.sapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: false
07-04 17:19:17.539 31219-31219/com.sapp D/SplashActivity: onStart
07-04 17:19:17.539 31219-31219/com.sapp D/SplashActivity: onResume
07-04 17:19:17.558 31219-31875/com.sapp D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
07-04 17:19:17.564 31219-31875/com.sapp D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
07-04 17:19:17.602 31219-31875/com.sapp D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
[ 07-04 17:19:17.641 31219:31875 E/         ]
Device driver API match
Device driver API version: 29
User space API version: 29
[ 07-04 17:19:17.641 31219:31875 E/         ]
mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Tue Jul 22 19:59:34 KST 2014
07-04 17:19:17.642 31219-31875/com.sapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
```

В период долгого запуска приложения, в профайлере такая картина:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В период долгой загрузки приложения, на устройстве такая ситуация:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это на экране можно видеть до появления в логе onResume, после чего отображается экран загрузки.

Тестировал на Api 21, 23.

Насколько я понимаю, долго происходит первоначальная инициализация, и связана она с загрузкой дополнительных библиотек. 
Как можно это ускорить или хотя бы отложить, чтобы показать экран загрузки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это особенности работы виртуальной машины `ART`. На самом деле, долгая загрузка кажется долгой изза оптимизации приложения после его установки. То есть, дивайсу нужно время не на запуск приложения, а на его *распаковку*. Соответственно, пока приложение не *распакуется*, оно не сможет запуститься.
 Проверить мою теорию вы можете удалив приложение, установив APK файл, подождав ~40 сек, и запустив приложение.

Comment: Насколько я понял, речь идет об AOT (Ahead-of-Time) компиляции,  пришедшая на смену JIT-компиляции, которая сразу переводит DEX-файлы в машинный код, на что тратится время. Я заметил, что при компиляции проекта с пустой стартовой активностью, которая ни на что не ссылается, при ручной установке установка происходит быстро, и при запуске начинается задержка, обусловленная  компиляцией. Если же я сделаю стартовой активностью рабочую активность, которая связана со всем проектом, то компиляция будет проходить во время установки (в т.ч. с Play Market), а запускаться будет быстро.

Comment: Однако, при первоначальной установке билда из Андроид Студии эта задержка видна сразу, отчего и возник мой вопрос. Чтобы это исправить, можно отключить предварительную компиляцию для тестовых билдов, добавив в build.gradle:

 default {
         manifestPlaceholders = [vmSafeModeEnabled: "true"]
 }
 buildTypes{
     release {
         manifestPlaceholders = [vmSafeModeEnabled: "false"]
     }
 }

а в манифест:

 android:vmSafeMode="${vmSafeModeEnabled}"